# Run function without duplicate

Tags: c++, c++98

I want to know if it's possible, to make the function run without duplicates?

If it's looping through array with numbers `1,2,2,3,4`  I would want the 2 to be run only once instead twice. Like `1,2,3,4`. How can I check if `tab[i]` has been already inserted? I need to do this in c++ 98.

```cpp
     std::vector<int> noDup(n);

 for(int k=0; k < n; k++) {
    bool exists = false;

    for(int c= 0; c < noDup.size(); c++) {
      if(tab[k] == tab[c]) {
        exists = true;
        break;
      }
      if(exists == false) {
        noDup.push_back(tab[k]);
      }
    }
  }

  for(auto c : noDup) {
    cout << c << " ";
  }
```

When I inserted number of elements in tab array 4,
I input `2,2,3,4` I got output `0 0 0 0 3 3 4 4 4`

Comment: what is `tab` ? Please post  a [mcve]

Comment: [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) may be helpful if the elements of `tab` can be compared for order.

Comment: @MikeCAT not in c++ 98.

Comment: @debooger3 `std::set` did exist in C++98. If you're unable to use it, you should probably figure out why exactly, and include it in your question.

Comment: Basically, you can sort the array, and compare each element with the previous one ...

Comment: I've edited my post with code I've got, can you please check and tell me what im doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did

```
      if(exists == false) {
        noDup.push_back(tab[k]);
      }
```

in wrong place. It have to be after checking all elements.

Also the vector `std::vector<int> noDup(n);` already has `n` elements and [`push_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) will add elements after the initial `n` elements.
It seems you want to pre-allocate without adding elements via [`reserve()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve).

The condition `tab[k] == tab[c]` is also wrong. It should be `tab[k] == noDup[c]`.

Another error is usage of `for(auto c : noDup)` (range-based for and `auto`), which is available from C++11 and not in C++98.

Fixed code:

```
std::vector<int> noDup;
noDup.reserve(n);

for(int k=0; k < n; k++) {
  bool exists = false;

  for(int c= 0; c < noDup.size(); c++) {
    if(tab[k] == noDup[c]) {
      exists = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(exists == false) {
    noDup.push_back(tab[k]);
  }
}

for(std::vector<int>::iterator it = noDup.begin(); it != noDup.end(); it++) {
  cout << *it << " ";
}
```

Better option is using [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set).

```
std::set<int> seen;
std::vector<int> noDup;
noDup.reserve(n);

for(int k=0; k < n; k++) {
  if (seen.find(tab[k]) == seen.end()) {
    seen.insert(tab[k]);
    noDup.push_back(tab[k]);
  }
}

for(std::vector<int>::iterator it = noDup.begin(); it != noDup.end(); it++) {
  cout << *it << " ";
}
```